# SQL Server 2008 R2 mirroring failing

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two Windows 2008 R2 (Amazon EC2) instances running SQL Server 2008 R2. I use 9TB striped disks (9x1TB EBS volumes) for storage. One server is running as principal and second one as mirror. Both started from the same image, database and tlog files located on striped disk. Mirror server failed 3 times in last 2 months with errors:

> EventID 823  The operating system returned error 2(The system cannot
>   find the file specified.) to SQL Server during a write at offset
>   0x00000048058a00 in file 'D:\TLogs*********_log.ldf'. Additional
>   messages in the SQL Server error log and system event log may provide
>   more detail. This is a severe system-level error condition that
>   threatens database integrity and must be corrected immediately.
>   Complete a full database consistency check (DBCC CHECKDB). This error
>   can be caused by many factors; for more information, see SQL Server
>   Books Online.

and

> EventID 1454 Database mirroring will be suspended. Server instance
>   'xxxxxxxxxx' encountered error 823, state 6, severity 24 when it was
>   acting as a mirroring partner for database '*********'. The database
>   mirroring partners might try to recover automatically from the error
>   and resume the mirroring session. For more information, view the error
>   log for additional error messages.

followed by

> EventID 19019
>   The MSSQLSERVER service terminated unexpectedly.

After this rebooting instance is necessary to restore mirroring.
First two times I thought it was hardware related (striped disk failure) and relaunched instance on new hardware. But the issue is back after few weeks again. It only affects mirror instances. Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Striped disk failed again today. First an error on disk 9 appeared, showing two 1MB chunks of unallocated space. Striped disk itself looked healthy and usable from Windows explorer with this error, but SQL Server couldn't access database files on it. I stopped SQL Server and striped disk failed completely (unusable). After instance reboot everything was back to normal, no disk/OS/SQL Server issues. There's nothing useful in Event log. As I mention in my first post, this only happens for mirros, principal instances launched from the same image never gave me any trouble.